# Change layout of LinearLayout that is inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-view

I googled a bit but I can't find solution to my problem.
So, I want change programmatically the `layout_marginEnd` to `5dp` of the `LinearLayout`.

But I can't because it always return me this error:

```
android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams
```

My xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MyContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/UnderMyContainer"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical|right">
```

Code:

```
private LinearLayout contZC;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

    contZC = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MyContainer);
```

Use of `contZC`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(contZC != null) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) contZC.getLayoutParams();
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            params.setMarginEnd(dpToPixels(25));
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            params.setMarginEnd(dpToPixels(5));
        }
    }
    else
        Log.d("Activity", "contZC = null");
}

private int dpToPixels(int dpValue) {
    Resources r = getContext().getResources();
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            dpValue,
            r.getDisplayMetrics()
    );
    return px;
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you try to change the margin

Comment: I edited my question, can you help me?

Comment: Where is the initialization of `contZC`?

Comment: initialization added sorry

Comment: You didn't post the xml that corresponds with the id `MyContainer`

Comment: Can you post the line the error message refers to? Is it: `contZC = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MyContainer);`?

Comment: Yes, the error was there at that line